# Chemfig - command arrow - alignment doesn't work

Tags: babel, chemfig

I'm writing my bachelor thesis. I wanted to insert a chemical equation, but the reactant and the product are not horizontally aligned well. I found in Chemfig manual a solution to this problem but when I write `\arrow(.center--.base west){<=>[\ce{H2O}]}`, TeXnicCenter returns 9 errors and in pdf document there is no equation at all. When I write only `\arrow{<=>[\ce{H2O}]}`, it works well ...

I'm using TeXnicCenter, MikTeX and SumatraPDF on Windows 7. I'm a beginner with LaTeX.

Thanks for help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
  AA
  % \arrow{<=>[xxx]} % works
  \arrow(.base east--.base west){<=>[xxx]}
  BB
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! You seem to use two custom packages. Can you make an example that shows the problem and that we can compile, too?

Comment: Thanks. Well, the example is above in the code:

    \schemedebug{true}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{*6(-=(-CH=[:0,0.8]O)-(-CH=[:0,0.8]O)=-=)}
    \arrow{<=>[\ce{H2O}]}
    \chemfig{*6(-=(-(-[:30]OH)(-[:-90]OH))-(-CH=[:0,0.8]O)=-=)}
    \schemestop

Comment: No: the example is not complete: a complete example starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` - I or someone else can copy and compile the example then _as is_ and reproduce your issue.

Comment: The code is above in my question. I erased some parts but the problematic one is there. I use two packages that my school provides with thesis template (bakalarska_prace_en, bakalarska_prace). You will need them too, I suppose? (I'm sorry, I'm a real beginner .. :( )

Comment: The code above produces: ``! LaTeX Error: File `bakalarska_prace_en.sty' not found.`` because both `bakalarska_prace_en` and `bakalarska_prace` are packages that aren't part of a usual TeX distribution. Are they needed for the error? If so you should provide a link where to get them. Removing them and the dots from the preamble produces the error `! LaTeX Error: No \title given.` and after that `! Undefined control sequence.` for `\ce`... that means I have to fix quite a lot of errors before I can even try to look at your issue.

Comment: When I fix them all the part between `\schemstart` and `\schemestop` works just fine, though!

Comment: In package bakalarska_prace they use another chemical package (achemso) but it's not for chemical reactions so I used chemfig. I don't know if these two don't colide together somehow ...

Comment: Seems to be a conflict between `babel` with `czech` and `chemfig`. I'll edit your example to a smaller one that reproduces the issue clearly. then your private files aren't needed any more

Comment: Thanks a lot. But you don't know how repair it, please?

Answer (score 6):

I was really a conflict between `babel` with `czech` and `chemfig`. I found the following solution on [LaTeX community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=23272):

```
\documentclass[oneside,czech]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\schemestart{\shorthandoff{-}}{}{}
\apptocmd\schemestop{\shorthandon{-}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
A \arrow(aa--bb) B
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Thanks for help, cgnieder!